# Issue with clang --analyze

Tags: c++, clang

Good day.

I am trying to run static analysis using clang --analyze.
The CFLAGS in my Makefile is quite long.

```
CFLAGS= -I$(RESOURCES)  -I$(IMPORTED_HEADERS) -I$(EXPORTED_HEADERS)  -isystem$(ATL_MFC_INCLUDE) -isystem$(SDK7INCLUDE) -isystem$(VCINCLUDE) -ferror-limit=0 -std=c++14 -fsyntax-only -Wmicrosoft -fms-extensions -fms-compatibility -Wno-microsoft-extra-qualification -Wno-non-pod-varargs -Wno-microsoft-cast -Wno-invalid-token-paste -Wno-inconsistent-dllimport -D_ATL_NO_HOSTING -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG
```

No matter where I try to stick --analyze, at the very beginning or the very end, I get this warning:

```
clang.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '--analyze' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Yet, when compiling a trivial cpp file, static analysis kicks in. e.g.

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    strcpy(NULL, "Hello");
    return 0;   
}
```

Is it a bug with clang? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you have `-fsyntax-only` in your command line.

`-fsyntax-only` instructs the compiler to check the code for syntax errors, and then quit, without proceeding with compilation.

By removing that flag, `--analyze` should kick in.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured it out, I wish it was mention in the docs.